# SD card on other phone

Tags: windows-8, sd-card

I have recently broke my Nokia Lumia 520. It has SD card with some apps in it. One of them are for tracking my budget other for my car's maintenance records. I have ordered new Lumia phone and I wonder if I would be able to put that SD card to the new phone and have all the apps and their data records.

Comment: Does the app you installed ask for sign in details ? If it does so, all your data will be saved in its database. No worries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unfortunately no**. The reason is that apps installed on the SD card are assigned a unique key. That key only exists on that phone, so the apps installed on that SD card will not run on another phone. Even if you reset the phone, you still cannot use the apps.

Comment: Why does it not work when you plug it back into the original phone? (Or in my case, copy the whole contents to a new sd?)